# Indexed function proof.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

**Prove:** $\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}f(A_{\lambda}) \subseteq f(\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}A_{\lambda}) $

**My proof**: Suppose $y\in \bigcup_{\lambda \in {\Lambda}}f(A_{\lambda}).$

Then,  $y\in f(A_{\lambda_{1}})$ for atleast one $\lambda_{1} \in \Lambda$.

$\exists x\in A_{\lambda_{1}}$ such that $f(x)=y.$ $\implies x\in \bigcup_{\lambda\in \Lambda}A_{\lambda} \implies y=f(x)\in f(\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda}A_{\lambda}).$

Are there any incorrect steps in my proof?

Comment: Looks correct. What about the reverse inclusion?

Comment: I have proved the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Looks correct. It's a pretty simple proof that can (and should) be done with something straight-forward like this

Comment: @Asaf Karagila Your are so diligent and selfless that I often saw you in the posts of MSE. ^-^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some steps redundant although the proof is right, and it can be simplified as follows.

*Proof.* The conclusion follows from:

\begin{align*}
y\in \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}f(A_\lambda)&\implies\text{there is some }\lambda\in\Lambda\text{ such that } y\in f(A_\lambda)&\\
&\implies y\in f(\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda)&\text{by }A_\lambda\subseteq \bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}A_\lambda.
\end{align*}

---

By the way we usually use (square) brackets instead of (round) parenthesis in $f(A)$ when $A$ is a set of elements from domain, i.e., write $f[A]$ instead of $f(A)$.